# <__main__.Find_Adj_node object at 0x0DE643E8> , class called under def function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have following code where the class and def is defined.
Here we are reading a file which has start node, end node and distance between two nodes.

Example:
1 3 100
2 4 200
..so on..

```
  import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    
    # STEP 1: Get the inout options to choose between shortest path and all configuration
    path_type = int(input("Choose the option1 or option2 "))
    
    if path_type == 1:
        st_nd = int(input("Enter the start node: "))
        ed_nd = int(input("Enter the end node: "))
    
    
    # STEP 2: Import the data file
    def import_data():
        global data_points_df  # Data_points
        global data_points_max  # NN
        global Dist  # Dist
        global data_points_arr  # NData_points
    
        # Read the data as data frame
        data_points_df = pd.read_csv('./Exercises/dp.txt', delimiter="\t")
        data_points_arr = np.array(data_points_df)
        data_points_max = np.max(data_points_arr[:, 0:2])
    
        print(data_points_df)
        print(data_points_arr)
        print(data_points_max)
    
    def Find_Adjacent_Nodes():
        global K
        global data_points_max  # NN
        K = np.array([])  # Empty Array
    
        for i in range(data_points_max + 1):
            result = np.where(data_points_arr[:, 0:2] == i)
            print(i, result)
            temp = data_points_arr[result[0], (result[1] + 1) % 2]
            print(temp)
            dst = data_points_arr[result[0], (result[1]) % 1 + 2]
            print(dst)
            print(Find_Adj_node(temp, dst))
            K = np.append(K, Find_Adj_node(temp, dst))
        return K
    
    
    class Find_Adj_node:
        Adj_nod = []
        Nod_dist = []
    
        def __init__(self, M, N):
            self.Adj_nod = M
            self.Nod_dist = N
    
    
    if path_type == 1:
        import_data()
        Find_Adjacent_Nodes()

'''

when I run the command I see the following message.


    9 (array([5, 7], dtype=int32), array([1, 1], dtype=int32))
    [7 6]
    [ 200 2000]
    <__main__.Find_Adj_node object at 0x0DE643E8>
```

I would like to check what is inside K and how it is assigned. Logically I understand the it has [7,6] and the corresponding distance value as [200 2000]. The thing is how to print it and see.

Tried with k.* some options, but could not figure out.

BR,
SemiCode